# Detecting loss of connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, client

I have a client and a server program in java. The server is sending data to the client over wifi. A break of wifi connection at the client causes it to throw an exception and get out of the receive loop. The server still keeps sending data. The method used by the server is oos.writeObject(). How can I detect the break of wifi at the client at the server and cause the server to get out of the send loop?

Comment: TCP or UDP or another protocol?

Comment: Th protocol used is TCP.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your client (under some types of failure modes of the wifi connection) notices immediately when the connection goes away is because the wifi interface is local to the client and the operating system tears it down as soon as it is detected as down. From the server's point of view, it's a faraway network link that fails.

When the connection goes down, at first the server will continue to buffer data. If the buffers (the server's operating system buffer plus the TCP window size) become full, the server will block if it tries to send more data.

Later, if the connection is still down, the server will declare that the connection has timed out and you will get an exception. If, instead, the connection comes back up, the buffers will empty and normal data flow will resume.

Even if you could, you don't actually want to change things so that server's connection times out immediately when any faraway network hop fails. If you did that, your connection would be very fragile: every little network reconvergence event or short transient failure would break your connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I just need to know whether there is some way similar to setSoTimeout() for read that can be used here to close the connection atleast after some fixed duration.

Comment: Sure: you could use signals, or cancel the thread that's doing the writing, or use non-blocking I/O and give up after the socket has not come available for writing after the desired amount of time, etc...

Comment: Can you direct me to some link that uses non-blocking I/O or signals to give up writing. How do we detect that the socket has not come available for writing?

Comment: There are thousands of examples to be found by googling. You detect that the socket has not come available for writing when a system call such as `poll()` doesn't return that the socket has become available for writing (`POLLOUT` in `revents`). In this case you'd have a timeout in the `poll()` which expresses how long you're willing to wait for the socket to accept new data, and if the timeout expires before any registered file descriptors have events on them (`poll()` returns 0) then you give up on this socket.